# PostgreSql Installation issue on Non English OS

Tags: postgresql

We were trying to install postgresql-9.6.2-4-windows.exe in french Windows OS.
Password "Télécharger" this throws exception

```
ex‚cution de l'initialisation aprŠs bootstrap...FATAL:  sÇ¸quence d'octets invalide pour l'encodage ¶® UTF8 ¶¯ : 0xe9 0x6c 0xe9
```

It is unable to encode UTF.

Then we have tried with Chinese password in the same OS, which gives the following  Error

```
Executing cscript //NoLogo "C:\Data/installer/server/initcluster.vbs" "NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService" "postgres" "****" "C:\Data" "C:\Data\d" 5432 "DEFAULT" 0
Script exit code: 1
```

Can anyone help on this issue??

Answer (score 0):

I think the OS character-set is conflicting with the database character-set and producing this error.

I would suggest you either change the OS character-set to `UTF-8` as well or change the database character-set to a windows based character-set like `windows-1252`

Comment: I have even tried chinese password on english OS postgresql-9.6.2-2-windows-x64 setup, same result.